# Who was the longest lived Highlander Immortal?

Tags: highlander, highlander-2, highlander-franchise

According to canon, Methos is considered the current oldest living 'active' Immortal at 5,162 years old. This of course is tempered by the revelation in 'The Source' that the Guardian and the Elder are both approximately 10,000 years old. Some would argue that the 'hibernating' Guardian and the 'sequestered' Elder, both of whom were cursed, don't count as 'active'. Is there any known Immortal who was 'active/normal' while he/she were alive that exceeded Methos's 5,162 years?

For the purpose of this question, what I would consider as 'canon' or 'authority' would be the movies,'Highlander' through 'Highlander The Source' and 'Highlander:The Series' (the 90s tv series) and commentaries thereon.

I don't know about books, comics or cartoons. In any case, I suspect they're too prone to shift in the wind with each new addition so would not be inclined to accept them as authority without good reason.

Comment: Before we start this- please link/define your use of 'canon' in this mess of a universe[s].

Comment: @Solemnity, I edited the OP to clarify my perspective.

Comment: You mean the 90s TV series, presumably.  The Adrian Paul one.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo, sorry. Yes the 90s tv series with Adrian Paul as Duncan MacLeod of the clan MacLeod.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding my search a bit, I find that in addition to the Guardian and the Elder, there appears to be at least two other Immortals that were/are older than Methos' 5,162 years (dob 3155 B.C.); 
Djer an Egyptian Pharoh and Dilijan a Neolithic from the Himalayas. Though I can't find a specific birth date for either, they both seem to be at least 1000 years older than Methos was at that time. The canon is a bit suspect but barring new information, I'll take what I can get at this point.

Reign of Djer - 3100–3055 B.C.E.

At some point in his life, Methos was living with a nomad tribe in Sinai. Distraught at the murder of his wife, he wandered the desert for possibly months until he was caught stealing figs and brought before the Pharaoh Djer. Methos soon realized that Djer was a fellow immortal. Djer, who according to Methos was the oldest immortal (DOB pre 4000 B.C.), planned to offer his head to Methos. Methos decided that he would avenge his wife's death by burying Djer alive. Shooting a poison dart at Djer while he slept, Methos bound him in burial wrappings and placing him in a sarcophagus. After Djer's 'death', Methos became Pharaoh Djet. In roughly 2001, Djer's sarcophagus was recovered and Methos presumably then actually killed him. (DOB pre 4000 B.C. - killed 2001)

Dilijan:

At some point during or before the Bronze Age Methos encountered an older immortal named Dilijan. Dilijan lead a band of immortals dedicated to improving the lives of mortals via healing, irrigation, etc. Dilijan's actions sometimes had drastic unintended consequences such as his early separate encounters with Silas and Caspian.

When Kronos turned on Dilijan and slaughtered his followers but Dilijan escaped. Later the Horsemen hunted Dilijan on Kronos' orders. They found Dilijan had created a new peaceful tribe of mortals and slaughtered, raped, and burned the villagers including Dilijan's wife then salted the ground. Again Dilijan escaped. The next time they searched for Dilijan they were unable to find him, eventually they assumed he had been killed. Later Dilijan told Methos that it had been easy to avoid Kronos' clumsy search but if Methos had been interested in finding him he doubted he could have hidden effectively.

Fast forward to 1853

Methos met and fell in love with an opera singer named Violetta under the alias Nathan. Methos confessed a version of his violent past to her. They were together for roughly a year when one of Dilijan's brainwashed followers slipped Violetta a slow acting agonizing poison - Dilijan's long delayed and elaborate vengeance on Methos. After being poisoned Violetta lingered for weeks before finally dying but only after exacting a promise from Methos that he would not kill the man that had poisoned her. She knew that if he went after Dilijan he would revert to the killer he had been before they met.

Fast forward again to early 2010

Dilijan was cornered by Methos who then turned Dilijan's terrible experiments on him as an act of disproportionate vengeance for Dilijan's murder of Violetta. Methos drove so much negative Quickening energy into Dilijan that Dilijan's mind was seared and destroyed, left so full of agony he could not form new memories, a useless quivering hulk of misery Methos condemned him to live. Dilijan is last seen raving and sobbing in a mental institution.

Finally we get to the oldest living 'active' Highlander Immortal: 
Dilijan DOB: pre 4000 B.C - Present

http://highlander.wikia.com/wiki/Methos

Answer (score 0):

There is Emrys, the oldest immortal of the time who was beheaded by Darius at the gates of Paris.
He would've thus been older than Methos, perhaps even as old as or older than the Guardian and the Elder. He was a good immortal and thus may not have participated in the greed/power-driven crusade for the source by the ancient immortals 10,000 years ago.
His birth period is speculative but approx 3.500 BC - 12,000 BC.

Answer (score 0):

Well after doing some research I found that no one actually knows when Emrys was born but it was a lot earlier that 12000 BC, more like 20000 BC. Read the following:

> "When Haraonos Emrys was born, probably during the Upper Paleolitic c. 20,000 B.C, his tribe lived in caves and worshiped animal totems. Emrys was their shaman, but during a ritual, he mixed one potion too many, and died from the poisonous herbs.  He revived as an Immortal and remained the shaman of his tribe through the centuries. He was there to witness the totems of his youth being replaced by mother-goddesses, and these being replaced by various pantheons. From other immortals, he learned about the Game, and later he taught many immortals as well. Against those who sought his head, he was able to defend himself successfully.
>
> Over the millennia, he was known by many names, but eventually the name he became known by among his peers was Emrys, and he became a legend. At the time of his death, he was the oldest living Immortal".

He was 20400 years old, four times older than Methos...

The point is is that there have been immortals much older than Methos and there may yet be. Man's history goes back almost 200000 years and immortality may have started from since then. I look forward to a revamp of the highlander universe and more powerful immortals..

Comment: Where is that quote from? You need to cite quotes otherwise it's considered plagiarism.

Comment: Also, without a source it is unsubstantiated.  You could have just made it up yourself right now out of thin air.